# Tutorial Vegetation Condition Index

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, ndvi, vegetation-index

Anybody here can  help me regarding calculating Vegetation Condition Index  (Kogan,2004) for Landsat?. Specially facing problem in NDVI_max and NDVI_min; which should be maximum and minimum value?

Answer (score 8):

[Kogan (2004)](https://calmit.unl.edu/people/agitelson2/pdf/IJRS-Letter-Mongolia.pdf) (p. 2891) provides the following formula for the Vegetation Condition Index (VCI):

```
VCI = 100 * (NDVI - NDVImin) / (NDVImax - NDVImin)
```

where,

```
NDVI = Smoothed weekly NDVI value  
NDVImin = Multiyear minimum NDVI value  
NDVImax = Multiyear maximum NDVI value
```

As you know, NDVI ranges from -1 to 1 and functionally ranges from 0 - 1. VCI rescales this to 0 - 100.

You can put this formula into practice by using raster algebra in your favorite GIS.

Comment: Thank you very much. Should I reclassify the NDVI values 0 to 1 from the main scene?

Comment: No, you should not reclassify the NDVI.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 10 Common Vegetation Indices and Their Applications in Remote Sensing. Hope it useful for you.
https://medium.com/p/4bd9bfdae3f3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).