# Does Modis offer MultiYear statistics?

Tags: modis, ndvi, vci

I'm trying to calculate the VCI data for my entire State.

I'm using MODIS's 16 day NDVI Average. From [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174933/tutorial-vegetation-condition-index), I see that I would need to calculate the Min & Max NDVI values for each pixel based on several year's data.

My state is covered by 4 different MODIS Scenes, and hence downloading and processing this area for multiple years would be a long and resource intensive process.

Is there any Dataset which gives the Min & Max NDVI Values based on long-term data?